# Queryproblem with mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have 2 collections in a mongodb database.
example:

```
employee(collection)
    _id
    name
    gender
    homelocation (double[] indexed as geodata)
    companies_worked_in (reference, list of companies)

companies(collection)
    _id
    name
    ...
```

Now I need to query all **companies** who's name start with "wha" and has/had employees which live near (13.444519, 52.512878) ie.

How do I do that without taking too long?
With SQL it would've been a simple join (without the geospatiol search of course... :( )

Answer (score 1):

You can issue 2 queries. (Queries I wrote are in JavaScript)

First query extracts all companies whose name starts with `wha`.

```
db.companies.find({name: {$regex: "^wha"}}, {_id: 1})
```

Second query can be like

```
db.employees.find({homelocation: {$near: [x,y]}, companies_worked_in: {$in: [result_from_above_query]} }, {companies_worked_in: 1})
```

Now simply filter companies_worked_in and have only those companies whose name starts with `wha`. I know it seems like the first query is useless in this case. But a lot of records would be filtered by $in query.

You might have to write some intermediate code between this two queries. I know this is not a single query solution. But this is one possible way to go and performance is also good depending upon what fields you index upon. In this case consider creating index on `name` (companies collection) and `homelocation` (geo-index) + `companies_worked_in` (employee collection) would help you gain performance.

**P.S.**
I doubt if you could create a composite index over `homelocation` and `companies_worked_in`, since both are arrays. You would have to index on one of these fields only. You might not be able to have a composite index.

**Suggestion**
Store the company name as well in employee collection. That ways you can avoid first query.

Comment: Well, then I would find the employees, which were/are working near that location, but I need the companies...

Comment: I have edited my answer. I know it might not look much elegant. But this is one possible way can consider. Performance wise its fine. The first query can avoided, if you store campany name as well in the employee collection.

Comment: another problem would be, that the order of the tags would not be in order of distance anymore (if I use "within", instead of "near", which I do).